# set cookies of other website using php

Tags: php

I have a website that I want to get the names of the company using the div but the problem is the link keeps redirecting me into the homepage of the website

this is the site http://us.kompass.com/

I found that the problem is the cookies, is it possible to set the cookies of the website that you want to get?
is it possible to do that in php? or any ways to block the redirect?

referrer doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot read or set cookies for another domain.